# Changing the type of specific element in a list - python

Tags: python, list

As a part of my code, I need to iterate to a specific index of my list (which is obtained from a csv file) and change the type of those elements from **str** to **int**. However, when I iterate through the indices, convert them, elements don't change their type to int.

I'm very confused about why and how I can do this?

```py
    def generate_order(bom, parts_cost_filename):

    myfile = open(parts_cost_filename,'r')

    # Retrieving the headers for each of the files part name and the price
    header =  csv.reader(myfile) 

    header_list = []

    for line in header:
        header_list += line
        break

    header_list = list(header_list)
    for number in header_list[1:1]:
        number = int(number)

    print(header_list)


    myfile.close()
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the code in the post.

Comment: `header_list` is already a list you declared that on line 4, no need for the extra `list()` conversion, and also `[1:1]` will be an empty list

Comment: [1:1] will be an empty list. When you iterate over it, you might not be able to do anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall the exact reasoning behind that, but basically, your `number` variable in the for loop is <s>immutable</s> **a separate variable and not a memory reference**, so if you assign a new value to it it does not change the original list.

You need to access the list value by indexing it with square brackets.

```
for index in range(len(some_list)):
    some_list[index] = int(some_list[index])
```

or better yet, use a more pythonic generator approach:

```
some_list = [int(x) for x in some_list]
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with mutability.

Comment: This is not mutability. This is because when you loop by doing for x in list, x is a seperate variable of the list item and not a memory reference of the item